# Open pdf in new tab with right click option ' open in new tab'

Tags: javascript, pdf, hyperlink, window, right-click

```js
function showPDF(pdfUrl) {
  var iframe = document.getElementById("pdfFrame");
  iframe.style.display = "block";
  iframe.src = pdfUrl;
  document.getElementById("fullscreenButton").style.display = "block";

  iframe.scrollIntoView({
    behavior: 'smooth',
    block: 'start',
  });
}

function openNewWindow() {
  var iframe = document.getElementById("pdfFrame");
  var pdfUrl = iframe.src;
  window.open(pdfUrl, '_blank');
}
```

pdf links are in the list with name pdfList.

`<a class="pdf-link" href="#" onclick="showPDF('https://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf')">pdf</a>`

when i right click and open in new tab it opens the same page not the pdflink

Comment: This is because right clicking is the `oncontextmenu` event. Not the `onclick`. Hence it doesn't trigger the function.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the script and let the browser handle it as it is supposed to.

Now you can left click to open in new tab and right-click to do whatever else you want (including open in a new tab)

```
<a class="pdf-link" href="https://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf" target="_blank">Open PDF in New Tab</a>
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. You're hard coding the `href` attribute, removing anything else that the javascript functions do.

Comment: @icecub it IS actually the answer to the question but should have some more information

Comment: @mplungjan I honestly don't agree, but that's because I'm not the one to judge how someone wants to make something work. OP clearly wants to use a Javascript function for whatever reason. Telling them to do something else feels like someone asking me to fix the breaks on their bike and me telling them to put other breaks on it instead of fixing them, just to use an analogy.

Comment: @icecub Poor analogy. Look up X/Y problem. Obviously OP's code does not work, so the best answer is one without code at all.